# HTML form for edit/delete array

Tags: php, html, forms, random, editing

In my blog I have a small PHP code for a welcome phrase or a reflexive quote this randomly when the page is refreshed or when a user or when someone enters.

Will there be any way to edit the contents of each array without needing to download/edit the file and re-upload it again via FTP?

my current code (all on same page) this file is for read the current quotes/phrases.

PHP Random:

```
        ###### inician las frases ######
        $hola1 = "Hola! Sea usted bienvenido, Por favor disfrute su estancia!";
        $hola2 = "Cada mañana nacemos de nuevo. Lo que hacemos hoy es lo que más importa.";
        $hola3 = "La acción es la llave fundamental de todo éxito.";
        $hola4 = "No vayas donde guía el camino, ve donde no hay camino y deja un rastro.";
        $hola5 = "Somos lo que hacemos de forma repetida. Por tanto, la excelencia no es un acto, sino un hábito.";
        $hola6 = "El éxito llega cuando la preparación se encuentra con la oportunidad.";
        $hola = array($hola1,$hola2,$hola3,$hola4,$hola5,$hola6);
        $welcome = $hola[rand(0, count($hola)-1)];         
        ###### inician frases ######
```

and my html code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h2>Frases de Bienvenida!</h2>
      <P><?php echo '<pre>'; print_r($hola); echo '</pre>';?></P>
    </div>     
  </div>
<div class="alert alert-success fade in">
    <strong>Hey!</strong> <?php echo $welcome; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

How could edit the content using HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't add them without accessing the php files , you have to use your panel 's file manager or use ftp  to edit the template file .

Comment: Seems impossible, I thought I could edit them using HTML. I'm still a newbie and don't know much about PHP. anyways thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: you welcome ,  the html is a client side language you navigator ( firefox / chrome .. ) is who execute the code but the php is server side so you have edit the actual code ;) . good luck